# How to fix and work with tree toc?(old syntax)

Tags: javascript

so i bought a site witch is connected to a gestional programm in office..

the site is a little old, it's fully compatible with all the versions of internet explorer but not with other browsers(opera,safari,chrome,firefox...)

the only piece not working is a menu not opening correctly, when you click on it it doesn't happen anything or in chrome it changes the image but it doesn't upload the links. it seems that it doens't upload things in the hiddenframe...
in chrome it gives error in loadchildren function.

in firefox it gives error in function Toc_click ()

```
TypeError: window.event is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

var eSrc = window.event.srcElement;
```

we searched for the problem and we think that the problem should be in this file
the problem should be a syntax problem, it's compatible in old browsers but not on the new ones. i cannot change completely the code as it is connected with other files(a lot) and sql server...

we already tried to change

```
      document.frames["hiddenframe"].location.replace(strLoc);
```

by

```
      document.getElementsByName("hiddenframe").location.replace(strLoc);
```

it doens't work and it doesn't work on IE either...

```
 /* TOC.JS */

var framesTop = parent.parent;

//var L_LoadingMsg_HTMLText = "Loading, click to cancel...";
var LoadDiv = '<DIV ONCLICK="loadFrame(true);" CLASS="clsLoadMsg">';
L_LoadingMsg_HTMLText = LoadDiv + L_LoadingMsg_HTMLText + "</LI>";

function caps(){
    var UA = navigator.userAgent;
    if(UA.indexOf("MSIE") != -1)
    {
        this.ie = true;
        this.v = UA.charAt(UA.indexOf("MSIE") + 5);
        if( this.v == 2 ) this.ie2 = true;
        else if( this.v == 3 ) this.ie3 = true;
        else if( this.v == 4 ) this.ie4 = true;
        else if( this.v == 5 ) this.ie5 = true;
        else if( this.v == 6 ) this.ie6 = true;
    else this.ie6 = true;
    }
    else if(UA.indexOf("Mozilla") != -1 && UA.indexOf("compatible") == -1)
    {
        this.nav = true;
        var v = UA.charAt(UA.indexOf("Mozilla") + 8);
        if(v == 2 ) this.nav2 = true;
        else if(v == 3 ) this.nav3 = true;
        else if(v == 4 ) this.nav4 = true;
    }
    if(UA.indexOf("Windows 95") != -1 || UA.indexOf("Win95") != -1 || UA.indexOf("Win98") != -1 || UA.indexOf("Windows 98") != -1 || UA.indexOf("Windows NT") != -1 || UA.indexOf("Windows XP") != -1) this.win32 = true;
    else if(UA.indexOf("Windows 3.1") != -1 || UA.indexOf("Win16") != -1) this.win16 = true;
    else if(UA.indexOf("Mac") != -1) this.anymac = true;
    else if(UA.indexOf("SunOS") != -1 || UA.indexOf("HP-UX") != -1 || UA.indexOf("X11") != -1) this.unix = true;
    else if(UA.indexOf("Windows CE") != -1) this.wince = true;
}

var bc = new caps();

////////////////////////////////////////////
// Not sure why this is here, it puts a scrollbar up when none is needed
// if("object" == typeof(parent.document.all.fraPaneToc)) parent.document.all.fraPaneToc.scrolling = "yes";
////////////////////////////////////////////

var eSynchedNode = null;
var eCurrentUL = null;
var eCurrentLI = null;
var bLoading = false;

function loadFrame( bStopLoad )
{
    if( "object" == typeof( eCurrentUL ) && eCurrentUL && !bStopLoad )
    {
      eCurrentUL.innerHTML = hiddenframe.chunk.innerHTML;
      eCurrentUL = null;
      bLoading = false;
    }
    else if( "object" == typeof( eCurrentUL ) && eCurrentUL )
    {
      eCurrentUL.parentElement.children[1].className = "";
      eCurrentUL.parentElement.children[0].src = "bs.gif";
      eCurrentUL.parentElement.className = "kid";
      eCurrentUL.className = "clsHidden";
      eCurrentUL.innerHTML="";
      eCurrentUL = null;
      bLoading = false;
    }
    else
    {
      bLoading = false;
    }
    return;
}

function GetNextUL(eSrc)
{
    var eRef = eSrc;
    for(var i = eRef.sourceIndex + 1; i < document.all.length; i++)
    {
        if( "UL" == document.all[ i ].tagName )
        {
            return document.all[ i ];
        }
        else if( "LI" == document.all[ i ].tagName )
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function MarkSync(eSrc)
{
    if("object" == typeof(aNodeTree)) aNodeTree = null;
    if("LI" == eSrc.tagName.toUpperCase() && eSrc.children[1] && eSynchedNode != eSrc )
    {
        UnmarkSync();
        eSrc.children[1].style.fontWeight = "bold";
        eSynchedNode = eSrc;
    }
}

function UnmarkSync()
{
    if("object" == typeof(eSynchedNode) && eSynchedNode )
    {
        eSynchedNode.children[1].style.fontWeight = "normal";
        eSynchedNode = null;
    }
}

function MarkActive(eLI)
{
    if( "object" == typeof( eLI ) && eLI && "LI" == eLI.tagName.toUpperCase() && eLI.children[1] && eLI != eCurrentLI )
    {
        MarkInActive();
        window.eCurrentLI = eLI;
        window.eCurrentLI.children[1].className = "clsCurrentLI";
    }
}

function MarkInActive()
{
    if( "object" == typeof( eCurrentLI ) && eCurrentLI )
    {
        window.eCurrentLI.children[1].className = "";
        window.eCurrentLI = null;
    }
}

function LoadChildren( eLink )
{
    var strLoc = "loadtree.asp" + eLink.href.substring( eLink.href.indexOf( "?" ) );
    document.frames["hiddenframe"].location.replace(strLoc);
}

function Navigate_URL( eSrc )
{
    var eLink = eSrc.parentElement.children[1];
    urlIdx = eLink.href.indexOf( "URL=" );
    if("object" == typeof(framesTop.fraTopic) && eLink && "A" == eLink.tagName && urlIdx != -1 )
    {
        if(eLink.target=="fraTopic"||eLink.target=="_top"){
            framesTop.fraTopic.location.href = eSrc.parentElement.children[1].href.substring( urlIdx + 4 );
        }else{
            window.open(eSrc.parentElement.children[1].href,eLink.target);
        }
        MarkSync(eSrc.parentElement);
    }
    else if("object" == typeof(framesTop.fraTopic) && eLink && "A" == eLink.tagName  && eLink.href.indexOf( "tocPath=" ) == -1 && eLink.href.indexOf( "javascript:" ) == -1 )
    {
        if(eLink.target=="fraTopic")
        {
            framesTop.fraTopic.location.href = eSrc.parentElement.children[1].href;
        }
        else if( eLink.target=="_top" )
        {
            top.location = eLink.href;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            window.open(eSrc.parentElement.children[1].href,eLink.target);
        }
        MarkSync(eSrc.parentElement);
    }
    else if( eSynchedNode != eSrc.parentElement && ( urlIdx != -1 || ( eLink.href.indexOf( "javascript:" ) == -1 && eLink.href.indexOf( "tocPath=" ) == -1 ) ) )
    {
        // START D.S.
        if(eLink.target=="fraTopic")
        {
            if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows") == -1) {
                var MyHref = eSrc.parentElement.children[1].href;
                do
                {
                    if (MyHref.indexOf("%2E") != -1) MyHref = MyHref.replace("%2E", ".");
                    else if (MyHref.indexOf("%2F") != -1) MyHref = MyHref.replace("%2F", "/");
                    else if (MyHref.indexOf("%3F") != -1) MyHref = MyHref.replace("%3F", "?");
                    else if (MyHref.indexOf("%3D") != -1) MyHref = MyHref.replace("%3D", "=");
                    else if (MyHref.indexOf("%26") != -1) MyHref = MyHref.replace("%26", "&");
                    else break;
                } 
                while (true);
                parent.fraTopic.location.href = MyHref;
            } else {
                parent.fraTopic.location.href = eSrc.parentElement.children[1].href;
            }
        }
        // END D.S.
        MarkSync( eSrc.parentElement );
    }
}

function Image_Click( eSrc , bLeaveOpen )
{
    var eLink = eSrc.parentElement.children[1];
    if("noHand" != eSrc.className)
    {
        eLI = eSrc.parentElement;
        MarkActive(eLI);
        var eUL = GetNextUL(eLI);
        if(eUL && "kidShown" == eLI.className)
        {
            // hide on-page kids
            if( !bLeaveOpen )
            {
                eLI.className = "kid";
                eUL.className = "clsHidden";
                eSrc.src = "bs.gif";
            }
        }
        else if(eUL && eUL.all.length)
        {
            // show on-page kids
            eLI.className = "kidShown";
            eUL.className = "clsShown";
            eSrc.src = "bo.gif";
        }
        else if("kid" == eLI.className)
        {
            // load off-page kids
            if( !bLoading )
            {
                bLoading = true;
                eLI.className = "kidShown";
                eUL.className = "clsShown";
                window.eCurrentUL = eUL;
                eSrc.src = "bo.gif";
                eUL.innerHTML = L_LoadingMsg_HTMLText;
                LoadChildren( eLink );
            }
        }
    }
}

function Toc_click ()
{
    var eSrc = window.event.srcElement;
    event.returnValue = false;

    if("A" == eSrc.tagName.toUpperCase() && "LI" == eSrc.parentElement.tagName)
    {
        var eImg = eSrc.parentElement.children[0];
        if(eImg) eImg_click(eImg);
    }
    else if("SPAN" == eSrc.tagName && "LI" == eSrc.parentElement.tagName)
    {
        var eImg = eSrc.parentElement.children[0];
        if(eImg) eImg_click(eImg);
    }
    else if("IMG" == eSrc.tagName)
    {
    }
    return event.returnValue;
}

function eImg_click(eImg)
{
    if("IMG" == eImg.tagName)
        {
            Image_Click( eImg , false );
            Navigate_URL( eImg );
        }
}

function Toc_dblclick()
{
    return;
}

function window_load()
{
    if( self == top ) location.replace( "default.asp" );
    var objStyle = null;
    if( bc.win32 && ( bc.ie4 || bc.ie5 || bc.ie6 ) && "object" == typeof ( ulRoot ) && "object" == typeof( objStyle = document.styleSheets[0] ) && "object" == typeof( objStyle.addRule ) )
    {
        window.eSynchedNode = document.all["eSynchedNode"];
        objStyle.addRule( "UL.clsHidden" , "display:none" , 0 );
        objStyle.addRule( "UL.hdn" , "display:none" , 0 );
        //--ulRoot.onclick=Toc_click;
        ulRoot.ondblclick=Toc_dblclick;
        if( window.eSynchedNode )
        {
            MarkActive(window.eSynchedNode);
            window.eSynchedNode.all.tags( "B" )[0].outerHTML = eSynchedNode.all.tags("B")[0].innerHTML;
            window.scrollTo(0,window.eSynchedNode.offsetTop-(document.body.clientHeight/2));
        }
        else
        {
            MarkActive(document.all.tags( "LI" )[0]);
        }
    }
}

window.onload = window_load;
```

suggestions?

Comment: Is it possible for you to narrow the problem down? Going through your entire code base is a bit of an undertaking.

Comment: said it, chrome gives error in load children fuction
and we tried already to change it a bit, but doesn't work